# do artists get paid more for iTunes streams or Youtube streams?

Tags: itunes, music, youtube

The main ways I listen to music on my computer are via iTunes or Youtube.

Which method should I use if I want the artists I'm listening to get the most money from my listening activity?

(Apologies if this is not the best Stack exchange to ask it, of course please move the question if you think there is a more appropriate place it belongs.)

Comment: I don't get paid anything for youtube, I do for iTunes. idk what the 'proper' deals are for major artists, but many of us simply see 'stolen' tracks on youtube.

Comment: Whenever I do you Youtube I always make sure to play the video actually associated with the artist's account, but even then I wonder actually how much they get.

Comment: Most aren't associated with the artist's account, that's the trouble. If you don't have an army of lawyers to keep a constant stream of takedown notices., you get nothing.